# Struggling with this practice interview question. Any and all help appreciated

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, huffman-code

Huffman coding is a method of encoding characters based on their frequency. Each letter is assigned a variable-length binary string, such as 0101 or 111110, where shorter lengths correspond to more common letters. To accomplish this, a binary tree is built such that the path from the root to any leaf uniquely maps to a character. When traversing the path, descending to a left child corresponds to a 0 in the prefix, while descending right corresponds to 1.

Here is an example tree (note that only the leaf nodes have letters):

```
        *
      /   \
    *       *
   / \     / \
  *   a   t   *
 /             \
c               s
```

With this encoding, cats would be represented as 0000110111.

Given a dictionary of character frequencies, build a Huffman tree, and use it to determine a mapping between characters and their encoded binary strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a tree for Huffman encoding and decoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587044/how-can-i-create-a-tree-for-huffman-encoding-and-decoding)

Answer (score 1):

#### Steps to build Huffman Tree

Input is an array of unique characters along with their frequency of occurrences and output is Huffman Tree.

> 1. Create a leaf node for each unique character and build a min heap of all leaf nodes (Min Heap is used as a priority queue. The value of
>    frequency field is used to compare two nodes in min heap. Initially,
>    the least frequent character is at root)
> 2. Extract two nodes with the minimum frequency from the min heap.
> 3. Create a new internal node with a frequency equal to the sum of the two nodes frequencies. Make the first extracted node as its left child
>    and the other extracted node as its right child. Add this node to the
>    min heap.
> 4. Repeat steps#2 and #3 until the heap contains only one node. The remaining node is the root node and the tree is complete.

#### [Huffman Tree build procedure with example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/huffman-coding-greedy-algo-3/)

Look at this tutorial here describe step by step build tree procedure..